# Measurement Base of Fusion Gate

Tags: measurement, bell-basis, optical-quantum-computing, linear-optics

I am reading [this article on "Fusion-based quantum computation"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.09310) and they claim there about Fusion Gate type-2 that it collapses the state to 2 types of eigenstates, and returns 2 results - $ZZ$ eigenvalue and $XX$ eigenvalue (Section II, page 3):

[image]

I can understand why it is true that it returns $ZZ$ eigenvalue (parity check) from the definition of this gate in this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.4193.pdf), where I collapse to a  state that is an eigenstate of $ZZ$:

[image]

[image]

My QUESTION:
**I can't understand how I am getting $XX$ results (parities of things like $|++\rangle$ (even) or $|+-\rangle$ (odd)) at the same time??**

Comment: I can see why the state is eigen value of XX and ZZ, but the success state is collapsing to a state which the eigenvalue of XX is predetermined. How can I have all the 4 options to measure?